# Symfony FOSUserBundle E-Mail Confirmation

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I just installed the FOSUserbundle and I want to have the e-mail confirmation enabled. Meaning if someone registers the user should get an email with an activation link.

I always get the following message:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in  \app\cache\dev\classes.php line 420
```

Here is the config.yml file:

```
#FOS User Bundle
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Dbe\DdddBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address:        info@dddd.ch
        sender_name:    Donaci
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true # change to true for required email confirmation
```

What might be the problem? The error occures on the app_dev.php/register/check-email page.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: The problem exists with other functions like resetting too. I guess the problem is with the email? where and how exactly do i link it? i'm using swift mailer.

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    port: "587" 
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Comment: Are you trying to run this in you `localhost`? What is the value of `%mailer_host%` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you work on localhost try to change the transport setting to gmail and set the username and password to the Google credential

**# app/config/config_dev.yml**

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode:  login
    host:       smtp.gmail.com
    username:   yourEmail@gmail.com
    password:   password_gmail
```

Comment: Somehow localhost was blocking the emails. It worked perfectly on the server, thanks.